# Use Pathauto with Image Name

Tags: 7, media, path-aliases

With **Drupal 7** I'm trying to use Pathauto to create aliases for images that we upload. The images are renamed with [File Field Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths). An example of what I'm trying to do

**What I'm trying to do**

- Image content type
- Has an Image Field (CCK), field_image
- Upload image with content type (example.jpg)
- example.jpg is renamed to Ax54jk.jpg (File Field Paths)
- mysite.com/node/523 is altered to mysite.com/Ax54jk (Pathauto)

I set a pattern for the Image content type of `[node:field_image]` which appears to yield *httpmysitecomsitesdefaultfilesAx54jkjpg*

So instead of creating *http://mysite.com/Ax54jk*, it creates *http://mysite.com/httpmysitecomsitesdefaultfilesAx54jkjpg*

While I was going for a unique URL, this is a bit more unique than I'd hope. Does anyone know how to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Comment: You can use `[node:field-image:file]` but it will generate `Ax54jkjpg`.

Comment: Thank you, that's a lot better. I may end up creating a simple module to orchestrate this with other modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unfortunate answser is that Pathauto does its deed after File Field Paths. A custom solution will be needed.